# Issue of mongodb.js (TypeError: qs.unescape is not a function) occurs in React app, but the function can be found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I want to use mongodb.js in a react created app as the code below.

```
  componentWillMount() {

    MongoClient.connect(uri, function (err, db) {

      db.collection('events').find().toArray(function (err, data) {

        console.log({ data });
      });
    });
  }
```

But the error occurs, said that "qs.unescape is not a function" , but I found the source and found out that it is a function, so how can this message occur?

```
TypeError: qs.unescape is not a function
```

[Screenshot for the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqIYJ.png)

```
const qs = require('querystring');
```

[Screenshot for the Source Code of qs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNMVp.png)

Comment: did you find any solution ?